# Simplifying the imports and exports with Typescript

Tags: typescript

So I'm new on JS and TS, not that new but kinda, so I'm exporting my components like this, and the list is getting bigger day by day.

```
import Notification from "./Notification";
import Confirmation from "./Confirmation";
import Button from './Button';
import Input from './Input';
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import Add from "./Add";


export {
    Notification,
    Confirmation,
    Button,
    Input,
    Dropdown,
    Add,

}
```

I want to know how to structure it better with vanilla JS or TS.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.ts`/`index.js` file, you can do `export .. from "..."` (where `...` is either a default import or named imports, and `...` is a filepath)

```
export * as Notification from "./Notification";
export * as Confirmation from "./Confirmation";
export * as Button from './Button';
export * as Input from './Input';
export * as Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
export * as Add from "./Add";
```

but this isn't very nice since you need to do `Notification.default` to access the default value.

Instead, if all your other files have a named export (`export Notification;`), you can do this:

```
export { Notification } from "./Notification";
export { Confirmation } from "./Confirmation";
export { Button } from './Button';
export { Input } from './Input';
export { Dropdown } from "./Dropdown";
export { Add } from "./Add";
```

Comment: I thought i can do something export * as utils and iterate all folders and upload their imports

Comment: Sadly you can't have an `index.ts` file that automatically goes through all folders, that's the point of you having to write the `index.ts` file